# android sdk 23 instrumentation permissions problems (java.lang.SecurityException)

Tags: android

trying to do simple APP to insert record into phone book.
It looks like I don't have problems with permissions, but system won't let create record anyway:

```
07-28 18:11:44.799  2304 10616 I UpdateIcingCorporaServi: Updating corpora: APPS=com.example.aero.myapplication, CONTACTS=MAYBE
07-28 18:11:45.362  2304 10648 I UpdateIcingCorporaServi: Updating corpora: APPS=com.example.aero.myapplication.test, CONTACTS=MAYBE
07-28 18:11:45.651 10663 10678 I GrantPermissionCallable: Permission: android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS is already granted!
07-28 18:11:46.255 10663 10678 I OK      : contact Permission to record allowed
07-28 18:11:46.255 10663 10678 D Info    : Creating contact: 123456789
07-28 18:11:46.259  2097  2114 E DatabaseUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: Proxy package com.android.providers.contacts from uid 10001 or calling package com.example.aero.myapplication.test from uid 10097 not allowed to perform WRITE_CONTACTS
07-28 18:11:46.260 10663 10678 E Error   : Exception encountered while inserting contact: java.lang.SecurityException: Proxy package com.android.providers.contacts from uid 10001 or calling package com.example.aero.myapplication.test from uid 10097 not allowed to perform WRITE_CONTACTS
```

any ideas? why that mystique?
once I run app it install 2 apk:

```
$ adb push /Users/aero/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.aero.myapplication
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.aero.myapplication"
```

and

```
$ adb push /Users/aero/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.aero.myapplication.test
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.aero.myapplication.test"
```

and only com.example.aero.myapplication has permissions in system, com.example.aero.myapplication.test doesn't have any permissions. I've lost little bit.

```
package com.example.aero.myapplication;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.filters.SdkSuppress;
import android.support.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.By;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivity{

    @Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);

    public Instrumentation instrumentation;
    private UiDevice mDevice;
    private static final int RECORD_REQUEST_CODE = 101;


    @Before
    public void before() {
        // Initialize UiDevice instance
        mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        //instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        assertThat(mDevice, notNullValue());
        // Start from the home screen
        mDevice.pressHome();
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
        String NAME = "TEST RECORD";
        String NMBR = "123456789";
        CreatePhoneBookEntry(context, NAME, NMBR);
    }

    public void CreatePhoneBookEntry(Context context, String NAME, String NMBR) {
        //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
        //        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS},
        //        RECORD_REQUEST_CODE)


        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Error", "contact Permission to record denied");
        } else {
            Log.i("OK", "contact Permission to record allowed");
            };

        /*
     * Gets values from the UI
     */
        // Creates a new array of ContentProviderOperation objects.
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    /*
     * Creates a new raw contact with its account type (server type) and account name
     * (user's account). Remember that the display name is not stored in this row, but in a
     * StructuredName data row. No other data is required.
     */
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder op =
                ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);

        // Builds the operation and adds it to the array of operations
        ops.add(op.build());

        // Creates the display name for the new raw contact, as a StructuredName data row.
        op =
                ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            /*
             * withValueBackReference sets the value of the first argument to the value of
             * the ContentProviderResult indexed by the second argument. In this particular
             * call, the raw contact ID column of the StructuredName data row is set to the
             * value of the result returned by the first operation, which is the one that
             * actually adds the raw contact row.
             */
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)

                        // Sets the data row's MIME type to StructuredName
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

                        // Sets the data row's display name to the name in the UI.
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, NAME);

        // Builds the operation and adds it to the array of operations
        ops.add(op.build());

        // Inserts the specified phone number and type as a Phone data row
        op =
                ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            /*
             * Sets the value of the raw contact id column to the new raw contact ID returned
             * by the first operation in the batch.
             */
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)

                        // Sets the data row's MIME type to Phone
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

                        // Sets the phone number and type
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, NMBR)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, "MOBILE");

        // Builds the operation and adds it to the array of operations
        ops.add(op.build());
        // Ask the Contacts Provider to create a new contact
        Log.d("Info", "Creating contact: " + NMBR);

    /*
     * Applies the array of ContentProviderOperation objects in batch. The results are
     * discarded.
     */
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log exception
            Log.e("Error", "Exception encountered while inserting contact: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into the same issue, but for a different permission.

The fix for me was simple, I had forgotten to add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.THE_PERMISSION" />` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

So maybe you should make sure that you have the required `<uses-permission.../>` and `<uses-feature.../>` in there.

Hope it helps..

Comment: That did not help either, anything else that you might be doing differently?